# Toast message when sending php form with Materialize

Tags: javascript, php, html, materialize

I am creating a form for my personal website, where the user will fill in the form with username and password. After clicking on the send button you should present a toast message with the message success!

```
<?php  if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
$usuario = trim(strip_tags($_POST['usuario']));
$senha = trim(strip_tags($_POST['senha']));
//echo $usuario.$senha;
echo "<script>
            $(function(){
                Materialize.toast('I am a toast', 4000)
            });  
    </script>"; } ?>
```

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tooltipped').tooltip({delay: 50});
  });
</script>
```

```css
<style>
            main {
                height: 90vh;
                padding: 20px;
            }
        </style>
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Toast</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>

<main>
    <div class="row">
        <form class="col s12" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s6 offset-s3">
                    <input id="usuario" name="usuario" type="text" class="validate">
                    <label for="usuario">Usuário</label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s6 offset-s3">
                    <input id="senha" name="senha" type="password" class="validate">
                    <label for="senha">Senha</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col s6 offset-s3">
                    <button type="submit" name="send" class="waves-effect waves-light btn"><i class="material-icons left">send</i>Send</button>
                    <a class="btn tooltipped" data-position="bottom" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="I am a tooltip">Hover me!</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

However I would like that instead of the echo "Sent with success!", A message of success or failure with the Framework Toast Dialog materialize.

Comment: Please fix the errors in your code.

Comment: este erro é por que o site não suporta php